# Div taking all horizontal space

Tags: css, html

Why?
i dint speficy the width, so it should be as big as content inside it.

```
#swfbox {
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 margin: 50px auto 0px;
 background: #310600;
 border: 3px solid #4b0900;
}
```

i have it centered and load swf files in it, so for it to work i have to set its width to the width of the swf file, which is bad since i every file has different width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<div>` elements are block-displayed elements, which means they default to 100% width unless otherwise specified.

If you want the element to expand based on its content, you might want to try setting the `display` property on the `<div>` to `inline` (or just use a `span` since it's essentially an inline-div).

Edit:

I guess inline didn't work quite the way I expected, so I learned something today. What you're going to want to do instead is to set `display: inline-block`, but that comes with it's own set of problems.

First, according to the [Quirks Mode page for the `display` property](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html), IE6 and IE7 only support `inline-block` on elements with a natural `display: inline` which means you need to use `<span>` elements rather than `<div>` elements.

Second, `inline-block` has its own set of quirks which you should read up on before using it, to prevent being surprised by further "gotchas". [This page](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) has a pretty good write-up on `inline-block`.

Comment: so how to change it to be as width as content inside it ?

Comment: @AgentConundrum yes, but not there is some padding issue.
inside swfbox i have another div, so swfbox is just to look nice, but now the top padding is non existing.

Comment: @Plaski: What padding issue are you seeing?

Comment: | |     | |
| | img | |
| |_____| |
|_________| it looks like this.

Comment: @Plaski: What image are you referring to? I'm clearly not getting the whole story here. Could you update your question with the *complete* HTML+CSS you're using? You can use jsfiddle.net if you'd like.

Comment: @Plaski: You're going to want to use `inline-block` for this, unless someone comes up with a better answer. I edited my answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

check this out for a solution: http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm
float the div that the swfs reside in (floats shrink to fit content)

> Relatively position the outer float
>   left:50%, so that the left edge is at
>   the middle of the page. Then
>   relatively position the inner float
>   left:-50% to shift it exactly
>   1/2 of the outer div's width to the
>   left, so that it is centered.

the link gives a full explanation and example.